# pandas DataFrame efficiently remove columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that is 1600 x 115,316 and mostly NaN. I want to remove every column that doesn't have more than two values in it. I have written some code that works but man alive it takes a long time.

```
for eachColumn in df.columns:
  if np.sum(df[eachColumn]) <= 2:
    df.drop(eachColumn, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 3):

Here's some sample data:

```
In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(shape=(10, 2))) * np.nan

In [19]: df.iloc[[2, 3], 0] = 2
```

So column `0` has 2 non-NaNs. Keep that and drop `1`.

```
In [20]: df.drop(df.columns[(~df.isnull()).sum() < 2], axis=1)
Out[20]: 
    0
0 NaN
1 NaN
2   2
3   2
4 NaN
5 NaN
6 NaN
7 NaN
8 NaN
9 NaN
```

Read it inside out. `.isnull` gives a DataFrame of Bools, flip the Trues/Falses with the `~`, sum that to get the count of non-null per column, select out the columns where the sum is less than 2 (column 1) and drop that./